# How to use pagination using jquery an jsp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, pagination, ejb

Now in my jsp page I have number of records come from oracle database.But I want to display limited number of records per time.How do I use pagination for this using jquery and jsp? I want to display 1-10 records at one time in my jsp. After click the next button I want to display my next record set.(11-20). In here values come from database are not fixed. My data table does not contain any headers.So it's not easy to use jquery data tables.How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific, anyway here's an example of what I did when paging the results of a search engine. I've used JSP and jQuery, maybe it can help you understand how to proceed: http://pastebin.com/XG40Vm2D